# Filter a log file in python to instantiate previous program state

Tags: python, logging, flask

```
import sched
import requests
from flask import Flask
import logging

logging.basicConfig(filename="log.log",
                    filemode='a',
                    format='%(asctime)s,%(msecs)d %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%H:%M:%S',
                    level=logging.DEBUG)
alarms_list = []
notifications = []
```

So alarm_list and notifications gets changed throughout when the program is running, then i need to recover the state using the log files, and the state is whatever they left off at.
Is there a way to log them as each time they change, then when initiating the program read the state of when they were last logged if ever. I assume the log file can get really long, so i would want to scan backwards, should i try to accomplish this with the logging module or just standard python file handling?

Comment: I think saving those lists into a json file or a database would be the best approach to achieve what you are looking for. Generally logs are not supposed to be used to store sensitive information rather the state of your script or program.

Comment: I completely agree however it is stated in my work that i need to be able to recover the state using the log files.